# EF5 model - code generation method and validators

Tags: c#, entity-framework, code-generation

In VS2010 by default, the code generating method would generate something like this for every property:

```
public global::System.String Header
{
    get
    {
        return _Header;
    }
    set
    {
        OnHeaderChanging(value);
        ReportPropertyChanging("Header");
        _Header = StructuralObject.SetValidValue(value, false, "Header");
        ReportPropertyChanged("Header");
        OnHeaderChanged();
    }
}
```

where `OnHeaderChanging` and `OnHeaderChanged` are partial methods so you could just implement them in a not-auto-generated file and validate the value.

In VS2012 the default generates something like that:

```
public global::System.String Header { get; set; }
```

- how can I add validation to the code generated in vs2012?
- why [isn't recommended](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj556581) to use the "old" style?